# Set text size on alert dialog in android

Tags: android

I have an alertDialog in android and the text inside is huge i want to change its size , and maybe change the look of the alert dialog also, how do i accomplish that. My app supports Api10.

```
 PR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("TitleSomething");

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ReadsPastStr,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Reads.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID",PastArr[which]);
                    startActivityForResult(i,ACTIVITY_EDIT);

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this , i've seen this on stackoverflow somewhere
 you wont change the font size but the whole theme

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext;
            if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
                themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar );
            }
            else {
                themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar );
            }


            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
```